# Is it possible to auto create directory hierarchy in .jar file?

Tags: java, jar

I'm rarely using java, so my knowledge of modern ecosystem is very limited :(. AFAIK, Java is heavy glued with directory hierarchy and file names: for example, if i have a .jar file with
"com.mycompany.myapp.WndMain" class, the corresponding .class file must be named exactly "WndMain.class" (case sensitive!) and be placed into "com/mycompany/myapp" directory tree inside .jar file (that is actually a .zip archive).

But while developing applications i don't want my **source code** files to be named CamelCase and scattered in some directory trees! It's **my** source code, after all. I prefer files to be organized the way it's comfortably for **me** to work with them, not for some stupid compiler and archiver :). I want a clean "src" folder with files like "wnd_main.java", "wnd_about.java" etc. Is it some **easy** way to automatically generate correct file names and directory structure during compilation, based on actual source code content?

Of course i can create script of my own - via Python, Ruby, Shell or whatever - that will read content of ".java" files, parse "using" and "class" directives, create directory structure, copy files, compile etc... But maybe all of this is already done years ago and all i need is something like "sudo apt-get install javamake"? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scons` build system perfectly creates directory structure according to content of `.java` files. Installation is as easy as `pypm -g install scons`.

Answer (score 0):

No, the compiler will not let you declare classes where the declared package name in the file (like `package com.mycopmany.myapp`) do not match the actual directory structure on disk.

This seems like a lot of work to go through to avoid having directories in your `src` hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

It will be a difficult task, as the package name inside each source file MUST be equal to the directory structure as @mattb said, but you can use some build tool like [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) (the most used one) to create the solution that you are looking for.

For example, if you have your source organized this way:

```
src
    foo
        class_1.java
        class_2.java
    bar
        class_3.java
        class_4.java
```

You can use Ant to copy all source files to a temp directory, compile and package then in a .jar, but as I said, you will have some problems, like name colisions (example: you can have classes with the same name in different directoties). All your classes must have different names and all classes must access each other as they are in the same package. All this problem is related to the solution that I propose. You can, off course, modify the code of the files that were copied to the temp directory, but I really don't think that all this is worth of try... I sinceraly recommend that you follow the "way to develop" in Java, using some IDE, following the [Java Code Conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/CodeConventions.pdf), etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is pointless. It's hard to find a question here.
But I'll try to answer:

1. Java requires your files to be **strictly organized** acordingly to its classnames.
   Think of Python, which *enforces* indentation. It does this to *eliminate* the need
   of coding conventions related to indentation.
2. It does this *for your own good*, to prevent situations of type:

   > How do I find this class in such a big project?
   >   It turns out I was writing a class / feature that is already present.
   >   For this project, *how* should I organize the files? Is there some convention?
   >   **What?!** 100 classes defined in a single file?
3. Don't like to work with the files and directory structure manually?
   **Use an IDE**, it will do that for you.
4. If you still want flexibility on Java, why not try some **Java-based languages**?
   Like Groovy, for example. Or Clojure, or Scala, or...
   They all work in the JVM, their syntax is compatible with Java's, but more **relaxed** and **permissive**.
   The same applies to the directory structure. **Bonus!** You can mix Groovy scripts with Java classes.

**Bottom note:** Actually, non-public classes **don't need to follow this convention**.
If by some strange reason you decide to declare one of your classes with **package access**,
it **won't be accessed from outside your package**, but you can give it the name you want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't strictly *have* to organize your `.java` files into a directory structure that matches the packages - `.class` files must be in such a structure but `javac` will accept a flat structure for `.java` files - however you will make your life much easier if you do so as pretty much all the higher level Java tools in the world expect you to follow this convention.  For example Ant relies on matching between the `.java` and `.class` directory structures to be able to tell which `.class` files are out of date with respect to their corresponding `.java`.  If the structures don't match it will recompile every `.java` file every time.

However the name of each `.java` file *must* match the name of the `public class` it defines (you can have several classes in one `.java` file but at most one of them can be `public` and its name must match the file name).  This is a requirement of the compiler, and it's not worth fighting against.

Comment: Really? I thought both `.java` and `.class` pathname _must_ match the classname. Never in my life I could have a public class declared in the wrong file. My compiler doesn't allow me to do so.

Comment: I suspect all IDEs will enforce a package structure for source files, but it's not technically a requirement of the compiler.  Try creating a simple `Hello.java` with a package declaration and then do `javac -d . Hello.java` - it will work, and put the `Hello.class` file in a package subdirectory.

Comment: It's not a requirement **as long as the classes aren't public.** But most of the classes are.

Comment: You're confusing my two points. Yes, the name of the file must match the base name of the (public) class, but `javac` does _not_ require the source files to live in a directory structure that matches their package names. Some IDEs might require that though.